# jQuery TableSorter Filter does not work on AJAX dynamic table

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla, filter, tablesorter

I am using jQuery TableSorter Filter for my Report Component at Joomla Framework.

I manage creating dynamic tables built by calling AJAX based on user database table selection. The TableSorter features such as sorting and pager work very well, but the Filter only works on the default table that is built whenever page loading, NOT on the dynamic tables built by AJAX.

Here they are my excerpt codes:

```
component/com_report/views/report/tmpl/default.php

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#tblReportMain")
            .tablesorter({debug: false, widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                                filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                                filterCaseSensitive: false})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});

        $(function(){
            . //some codes to be hidden for simplicity 
            .

            $('#buttonGenerateReport').live('click', function() {
                . //some codes to be hidden for simplicity 
                .

                if (aryColTableChecked.length > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "index.php?option=com_report&view=report&format=raw&task=showSelectedReport",
                            data: {
                                dbTableName: selectedDBTable,
                                dbTableColumns: aryColTableChecked
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                        $("#tblReportMain").remove();
                                        $("#divReportContent").html(result);
                                        $("#tblReportMain")
                                            .tablesorter({debug: false, widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
                                            .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                                                                filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                                                                filterCaseSensitive: false})
                                            .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});
                                        // let the plugin know that we made a update 
                                        $("#tblReportMain")
                                            .trigger("update")
                                            .trigger("appendCache")
                                            .trigger("applyWidgets");
                                    },
                            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        if (textStatus !== null) {
                                            alert("error: " + textStatus);
                                        } else if (errorThrown !== null) {
                                            alert("exception: " + errorThrown.message);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            alert ("AJAX error undefined");
                                        }
                            }
                    });
    . //some codes to be hidden for simplicity 
    .
    .          

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="50%">
                Search: <input name="filter" id="filter-box" value="" maxlength="30" size="30" type="text">
                        <input id="filter-clear-button" type="submit" value="Clear"/>

            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="right" width="50%">
                Export: <button id="buttonExportCSV" type="button" onclick="return false;"><?php echo JText::_('COM_REPORT_BUTTON_EXPORT_CSV'); ?></button>
                        <button id="buttonExportXLS" type="button" onclick="return false;"><?php echo JText::_('COM_REPORT_BUTTON_EXPORT_XLS'); ?></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

At my component controller file to build the dynamic table is as follow:

```
component/com_report/controller.php

    /*
     * Process to showSelectedReport
     * This function is called by JQuery Ajax function at object Report View default.php
     */
    public function showSelectedReport()
    {
        $dbTableName = JRequest::getVar('dbTableName', '', 'post', 'string');
        $dbTableColumns = JRequest::getVar('dbTableColumns', '', 'post', 'array');

        if (!empty($dbTableName)) {
            $model =  $this->getModel();

            if (!($model->showSelectedReport($dbTableName, $dbTableColumns, $rows, $pageNav, $lists))) {
                if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
                    JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                    return false;
                }
            }

            echo '<table id="tblReportMain" class="tablesorter">';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';

            foreach($dbTableColumns as $dbTabColNames)
               echo '<th>' . JText::_($dbTabColNames) . '</th>';

            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';

            echo '<tbody>';

            $k = 0;

            for($i=0, $n=count($rows); $i < $n ; $i++){
                $row = &$rows[$i];

                echo '<tr class="row' . $k . '">';

                foreach($row as $rowVal) {
                    echo '<td>' . $rowVal . '</td>'; 
                }

                echo '</tr>';

                $k = 1 - $k;
            }

            echo '</tbody>';

            echo '<tfoot>';
            echo '<tr>';

            foreach($dbTableColumns as $dbTabColNames)
               echo '<th>' . JText::_($dbTabColNames) . '</th>';

            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tfoot>';
            echo '</table>';
        } else
            echo '<table><tr><td>Cannot get the selected Table Information</tr></td></table>';
    }
```

Whenever I put character(s) into the "filter-box" input, there is no response at the dynamic table, but the default table will be filtered. When I click the button "filter-clear-button", it will refresh the whole page and go back to the default table.

As you can see my above codes, I have tried to use solutions discussed at [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247305/using-jquery-tablesorter-on-dynamically-modified-table)  and also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124235/how-to-fire-event-handlers-after-ajax-content-has-loaded-in-jquery) , but it still cannot work.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! :-) Just to share with you all what I have done, in case you encounter same problem like me.

```
component/com_report/views/report/tmpl/default.php

                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "index.php?option=com_report&view=report&format=raw&task=showSelectedReport",
                            data: {
                                dbTableName: selectedDBTable,
                                dbTableColumns: aryColTableChecked
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                        $("#tblReportMain").remove();
                                        $("#divReportContent").html(result);

                                        $("#tblReportMain")
                                            .tablesorter({debug: false, widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
                                            .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                                                                filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                                                                filterCaseSensitive: false})
                                            .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});
                                        // let the plugin know that we made a update 
                                        $("#tblReportMain")
                                            .trigger("update")
                                            .trigger("appendCache")
                                            .trigger("applyWidgets");
                                    },
```

changed to:

```
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "index.php?option=com_report&view=report&format=raw&task=showSelectedReport",
                            data: {
                                dbTableName: selectedDBTable,
                                dbTableColumns: aryColTableChecked
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                        //$("#tblReportMain").remove();
                                        //$("#divReportContent").html(result);
                                        $("#tblReportMain").html(result);

                                        $("#tblReportMain")
                                            .tablesorter({debug: false, widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
                                            .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                                                                filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                                                                filterCaseSensitive: false})
                                            .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});
                                        // let the plugin know that we made a update 
                                        $("#tblReportMain")
                                            .trigger("update")
                                            .trigger("appendCache")
                                            .trigger("applyWidgets");
                                    },
```

and at my Component controller.php I do not need to return the "table" HTML tag anymore. Therefore I remarked following code lines:

```
       // echo '<table id="tblReportMain" class="tablesorter">';
       // echo '</table>';
```

and I also add JQuery event for button "filter-clear-button" is as follow:

```
        $('#filter-clear-button').live('click', function() {
            if ((typeof selectedDBTable == 'undefined') || selectedDBTable == 'None') {
                return true;
            } else {
                $('#buttonGenerateReport').click();
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: I have almost the same problem, can you please take a look at my question and see if you can help me out. Thank you so much.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451260/tablesorter-filter-widget-stops-working-after-update-on-all-browsers-no-error-m